# Terminal Block substitute?

Tags: connector, ribbon-cable

I am trying to find a substitute for a terminal block like this: [image: Female Terminal Block]

Are there any connectors which come with wires already crimped in, but can be used with the male version of the above terminal block.

This is the male version:
[image: Male phoenix connector]

Its just that I have a lot of terminal blocks in my unit and I have too many wires to screw into the terminal block and some of them come out by wiggling the wire. It would be really helpful if I can find a connector with ribbon cable which can be used with the male connector.

Comment: knowing the manufacturer and model would help...

Comment: A ribbon cable with that pitch would be rather unlikely.

Comment: Not an answer, but it's common to improve the quality of these "screw-terminal" connections by crimping a [ferrule](http://www.ferrulesdirect.com/electrical/WIRE_FERRULES.htm) to the end of the wire before you attach it...

Comment: Please read the rules for this site. Specific product recommendation are not allowed.